# Retrieve paypal customer Information Using a valid access token

Tags: php, ios, curl, paypal-sandbox

# Header 1 # here is my code it return error:The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request

```
$access_token= "A015DwHUnZn-MCHk4n4ONHWyjjxbAA7jypf-Yn.B3Vzl06w";
         //  $access_token= $result3->refresh_token;
            $ch4 = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid");
            curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Content-Type: Application/json');
            curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Accept-Language:en_US');
            curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token);
            curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
          //  $information = curl_getinfo($ch4);

            $result4 = curl_exec($ch4);
            if(curl_errno($ch4)){
                echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch4);
            }
            curl_close($ch4);
            $result4 = json_decode($result4);
            echo "USER INFO";
            print_r($result4);
```

Comment: Maybe, you need to add some postfields before posting? Without required parameters, of course you will get `400: Bad request`.

Comment: curl -v https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid \ 
    -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer WfXdnxmyJtdF4q59ofxuQuAAk6eEV-Njm6puht3Nk3w"  i think no need of post value